# Does Google Analytics support real time reporting for custom dimensions?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, universal-analytics

I've already verified that my GTM and GA are linked correctly, and I've got a couple of `virtual pageviews` working (i.e. I can see them in the GA realtime report). But, I'd like to attach some metadata to these virtual pageviews, and I thought I'd accomplish this using `custom dimensions`.

This is how I've got it setup. In my pageview tag (the one that corresponds to a virtual pageview), I've set a couple of custom dimensions, as such:

```
Index | Dimension
1     | {{D1}}
2     | {{D2}}
```

where D1, and D2 are dataLayer variable macros.

I've also made sure to create these custom dimensions in my GA properties. Both are user scoped and have names that correspond to the dataLayer variable name (not the macro name).

I've set my GTM container to preview mode and checked the requests being sent, and the dimension looks like it's being sent correctly:

```
Dimension: {1: "d1 val", 2: "d2 val"}
```

Lastly, I'm setting these fields accordingly in the dataLayer whenever a fire a virtual pageview event (that triggers the pageview tag with the virtual url).

However, I'm not sure where to look for them in my GA report. They don't appear to be anywhere in the realtime report.

That gets me wondering, are custom dimensions not supported in real time reporting and I simply should just wait for GA to process them? Or should I assume something's wrong with how I'm setting it up?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

They are not supported at this time.

Here is a list of the supported realtime dimensions and metrics:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/dimsmets/

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I was wondering if my setup is correct (or if I'm even using custom dimensions for the correct purpose). I've scoured the web, but I don't really understand the difference between using custom dimensions and the `Fields to Set` aspect of a tag.